# SQL Request with Timestamp

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm using C# to do a request to a SQL server. The request need to be between 2 Timestamps (date and hour). The problem is if I put date only (2015-04-15) it works but if I put time behind (2015-04-15 16:00:00) it doesn't work anymore and show the error : "Close to '16' the syntax is incorrect."

I try different things but I can't find the way.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime Endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d") + " " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).Hour.ToString("00") + ":00:00");
DateTime Starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d") + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00") + ":01:00");

string time = string.Empty;

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("...");
sqlCon.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(TimeStamp) FROM net WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN " + Starttime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " AND " + Endtime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), sqlCon);

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(); //Error comes from here
while (reader.Read())
{
    time = reader[0].ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Do you have any idea to make it?

Comment: Use SQL Date Casting in Your query

Comment: Or just add single quotes around the dates `WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '"...`

Comment: Also, just to be sure:  `TimeStamp` is of type `DateTime` in the database, yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about making this a parameterized query, as in:

```
// Somewhere in your class declaration:
// Fixed parameterized query text as a constant.
private const string TimeRangeQuerySQL = 
    "SELECT COUNT(TimeStamp) FROM net WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN @starttime AND @endtime";

// ...
var cmd = new SqlCommand(TimeRangeQuerySQL, sqlCon);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@starttime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Starttime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Endtime;

var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

// ...
```

Note that it is good practice to use parameterized queries instead of trying to assemble a query string yourself, so that you don't expose yourself to SQL injection attacks. You may want to read the story of [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Not only does it prevent sql injection attacks (not strictly necessary for this specific query because we have a safe known input) it helps use cached query plans if you execute the same query twice with different values.